# Is there a god of work?

Tags: gods

I know there are many deities, each dealing with various areas of life, each with various characteristics.

**But is there one god or godness dedicated to work?**

In particular, I know that Saraswati deals with the works of the arts, she assists artists such as writers for example, **but is there a more general divinity for work?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vishwakarma Worshipping by Carpenters, Divine Architect & the Divine Engineer of the Hindus. Vishwakarma Jayanti is a day of celebration for Vishwakarma, a Hindu god, the divine architect.

Comment: Can you add some quote from Purana/Veda to support your answer?

Comment: It seems that Vishwakarma is also not a deity of work in general, he is quite specific.

Comment: This article from Wikipedia gives more information. Accordingly, he is also mentioned in Rigveda.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishvakarma